# Grape API gem: How to display associated Models as nested JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, ruby-grape

I'm currently building a API to access all posts on a blog for a specific owner.
I'd like to display them as nested json under the Blog model.

```
class API < Grape::API
format :json
prefix "api"
resource "posts" do
  get ':id' do
    owner = Owner.find(params[:id])
    present owner.blogs.each do |b|
        present b
        b.posts.each do  |p|
            present p
        end
    end
  end
end
end
```

It's safe to assume that a Owner has many blogs & in turn has many posts.

source:
https://github.com/intridea/grape

Comment: You need to ask an actual question - it may help to explain the results you are getting (so I don't have to fire up your code to check). I'm assuming the output isn't what you expect - I *think* this will output the list of blogs, as the last `present` that runs is the outermost one that will output `owner.blogs`. Have you tried using `grape-entity`?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you could find useful the grape-entity gem: https://github.com/intridea/grape-entity

With that you can define a "nested entity" for your model:

```
module YourApp
  module Entities
    class Blog < Grape::Entity
      expose :id, :blog_title
      expose :posts, using: YourApp::Entities::Post
    end

    class Post < Grape::Entity
      expose :id, :post_title
    end
  end
end
```

And than, in the endpoint:

```
# ...
present owner.blogs, with: YourApp::Entities::Blog
# ...
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that the `present` method used in the OP does not "build" up over multiple calls (as it looks like the OP is attempting to do), but simply sets the  output for the route. Your answer provides the nested structure in one method call via `grape-entity`, it would also be possible to have a method `Owner.blogs_structure` that returned a deep array of hashes by iterating through the model attributes directly. Basically `grape-entity` adds a nice declarative syntax for doing just that.